# Subdivision modifier messes up the edge

Tags: modifiers, edges, subdivision-surface

In the object view mode it creates those arch type edges. What can i do to fix it? I tried making them sharp but it wont work :(
What causes this (I think subdiv modifier)?

**[image: In edit mode]**

[image: In object mode]
[image: Another angle]

In the object view mode it creates those arch type edges. What can i do to fix it? I tried making them sharp but it wont work :(
What causes this (I think subdiv modifier)?

Comment: it's hard to understand what you mean, but why is your object so high-poly?

Comment: because im using displace modifier to make the pattern on my object :)
Just look at the edges in edit mode and after that check the object view mode

Comment: Woooooah! This mesh is very high poly you can barely make changes to this mesh through edit mode. I would recommend you to bring down the number of faces to make it a low poly mesh therefore making it is easier to edit and modify through edit mode. Also adding a subdivision modifier to a high poly mesh destroys the mesh as it makes some edges overlap with each other unless the mesh consists of many faces because of the subdivision modifier.

Comment: If you are referring to the interior faces shown in the second screenshot, I think the only way that subsurf could introduce those would be if the geometry is non-manifold.  They look more like the kind of artifact you get when you use the spin tool and have overlapping geometry.  Can you share your blend file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) If not, what does the model look like before you add the subsurf?

Comment: I cant do that because I have displace modifier which makes the pattern appear on my object

Comment: could you share your file,pls?

Comment: If you need high density you can use a Subdivision Surface modifier above your Displace modifier, this way you don't need to subdivide your mesh, you can keep low-poly and bevel etc

Comment: Ohhh ive mistaken the edge curls itself even without the modifier. Cant understand the problem :/